# Hit and Double function gets called repeatedly- on one press

Tags: lua, roblox

I have been trying to make a roblox game recently, that has a card game built in using GUI, etc. Currently I am implementing the logic for the game, and when I went to test it; it seems as if sometimes when I click either `Hit()` or `Double()` *it decides it wants **3 cards** instead of **1 card***, I am assuming that somewhere in my code im calling it twice on accident, but I have gone over it and haven't been able to see it; so I am starting to think it is something else. Ill attach my code below, if anyone has any clues on why this doesn't work that would be really appreciated. Don't spoonfeed me code, just give me documentation or some line numbers.

Thanks :D

```lua
local function Hit(player, Hand)
    if #deck == 0 then
        shuffleTable(deck)
    end

    local newCard = table.remove(deck, 1)
    local newCardTexture = cardTextures[newCard]

    -- Add the new card to the player's hand
    table.insert(Hand, newCard)
    local handTotal = CalculateHandTotal(Hand)
    player.PlayerGui.Blackjack.Main.PlayerTotal.Text = handTotal

    -- Update the player's hand display
    local templateCard = game.ReplicatedStorage.CardImages.FirstCard:Clone()
    templateCard.Name = "NewCard"  -- Change the name if necessary
    templateCard.Image = newCardTexture
    templateCard.Parent = player.PlayerGui.Blackjack.Main.PlayerCards

    if tonumber(player.PlayerGui.Blackjack.Main.PlayerTotal.Text) > 21 then
        print("You busted!")
        return false
    end
    return true
end
-- Function to handle the "Stand" action
local function Stand(player, playerHand, dealerHand)
    while tonumber(player.PlayerGui.Blackjack.Main.DealerTotal.Text) < 17 do
        dealerTotal = CalculateHandTotal(dealerHand)
        player.PlayerGui.Blackjack.Main.DealerTotal.Text = dealerTotal

        if dealerTotal > 17 then
            break
        end

        if #deck == 0 then
            shuffleTable(deck)
        end

        local newCard = table.remove(deck, 1)
        local newCardTexture = cardTextures[newCard]
        -- Add the new card to the dealer's hand
        table.insert(dealerHand, newCard)


        -- Update the dealer's hand display
        local templateCard = game.ReplicatedStorage.CardImages.FirstCard:Clone()
        templateCard.Name = "NewCard"  -- Change the name if necessary
        templateCard.Image = newCardTexture
        templateCard.Parent = player.PlayerGui.Blackjack.Main.DealerCards
    end

    playerTotal = tonumber(player.PlayerGui.Blackjack.Main.PlayerTotal.Text)
    -- Update the dealer's total display

    -- Implement your win/lose logic based on the final dealer total and player total
    if dealerTotal > 21 or dealerTotal < playerTotal then
        -- Dealer busts or player has a higher total, player wins
        -- You can implement the reward or outcome here
        print("You won")
    else
        -- Dealer has a higher total, player loses
        -- Implement the outcome accordingly
        print("You lost :(!")
    end
end


local function Double(player, playerHand, dealerHand)
    -- Double the player's bet (if you have a betting system)
    -- Perform a "Hit" and then "Stand"
    Hit(player, playerHand)
    Stand(player, playerHand, dealerHand)
end

game.ReplicatedStorage.StartBlackjack.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr)
    local dealerCards = plr.PlayerGui.Blackjack.Main.DealerCards
    for _, child in ipairs(dealerCards:GetChildren()) do
        if child.Name ~= "FirstCard" and child.Name ~= "TextLabel" and child.Name ~= "UIListLayout" then
            child:Destroy()
        end
    end

    local playerCards = plr.PlayerGui.Blackjack.Main.PlayerCards
    for _, child in ipairs(playerCards:GetChildren()) do
        if child.Name ~= "FirstCard" and child.Name ~= "SecondCard" and child.Name ~= "UIListLayout" then
            child:Destroy()
        end
    end


    if #deck == 0 then
        shuffleTable(deck)
    end

    local dealerFirstCard = table.remove(deck, 1)
    local dealerFirstCardTexture = cardTextures[dealerFirstCard]
    plr.PlayerGui.Blackjack.Main.DealerCards.FirstCard.Image = dealerFirstCardTexture

    local dealerSecondCard = table.remove(deck, 1)
    local hiddenCard = game.ReplicatedStorage.CardImages.TextLabel:Clone()
    hiddenCard.Parent = plr.PlayerGui.Blackjack.Main.DealerCards

    local playerFirstCard = table.remove(deck, 1)
    local playerFirstCardTexture = cardTextures[playerFirstCard]
    plr.PlayerGui.Blackjack.Main.PlayerCards.FirstCard.Image = playerFirstCardTexture

    local playerSecondCard = table.remove(deck, 1)
    local playerSecondCardTexture = cardTextures[playerSecondCard]
    plr.PlayerGui.Blackjack.Main.PlayerCards.SecondCard.Image = playerSecondCardTexture

    local playerTotal = GetCardValue(playerFirstCard) + GetCardValue(playerSecondCard)
    plr.PlayerGui.Blackjack.Main.PlayerTotal.Text = playerTotal

    local dealerTotal = GetCardValue(dealerFirstCard)
    plr.PlayerGui.Blackjack.Main.DealerTotal.Text = dealerTotal

    -- Initialize player data
    Hand = {playerFirstCard, playerSecondCard}
    Total = plr.PlayerGui.Blackjack.Main.PlayerTotal
    Cards = {
        ["Card1"] = plr.PlayerGui.Blackjack.Main.PlayerCards.FirstCard,
        ["Card2"] = plr.PlayerGui.Blackjack.Main.PlayerCards.SecondCard,
    }

    -- Connect the GUI buttons to the corresponding actions
    local hitButton = plr.PlayerGui.Blackjack.Main.Hit
    local standButton = plr.PlayerGui.Blackjack.Main.Stand
    local doubleButton = plr.PlayerGui.Blackjack.Main.Double
    local gameOver = false  
    
    hitButton.Transparency = 0
    standButton.Transparency = 0
    doubleButton.Transparency = 0
    hitButton.TextTransparency = 0
    standButton.TextTransparency = 0
    doubleButton.TextTransparency = 0

    hitButton.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
        if hitButton.Transparency <= 0 then
            if gameOver then
                return -- Exit the handler if the game is already over
            end
                
            if Hit(plr, Hand) == false then
                gameOver = true
                print("Made game quit")
                
                hitButton.Transparency = 0.6
                hitButton.TextTransparency = 0.6
                
                standButton.TextTransparency = 0.6
                standButton.Transparency = 0.6
                
                doubleButton.Transparency = 0.6
                doubleButton.TextTransparency = 0.6
            end
            
            
        else
            return
        end
        
    end)

    standButton.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
        if standButton.Transparency <= 0 then
            if gameOver then
                return -- Exit the handler if the game is already over
            end
            
            s, e = pcall(function()
                plr.PlayerGui.Blackjack.Main.DealerCards.TextLabel:Destroy()
            end)
            
            local newCard = game.ReplicatedStorage.CardImages.FirstCard:Clone()
            newCard.Name = "RemoveHiddenCard"
            newCard.Parent = plr.PlayerGui.Blackjack.Main.DealerCards
            newCard.Image = cardTextures[dealerSecondCard]

            print("Standing")
            Stand(plr, Hand, {dealerFirstCard, dealerSecondCard})
            print("Completed")
            
            hitButton.Transparency = 0.6
            hitButton.TextTransparency = 0.6

            standButton.TextTransparency = 0.6
            standButton.Transparency = 0.6

            doubleButton.Transparency = 0.6
            doubleButton.TextTransparency = 0.6
        else
            return
        end
    end)

    doubleButton.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
        if doubleButton.Transparency <= 0 then
            if gameOver then
                return
            end
            
            Double(plr, Hand, {dealerFirstCard, dealerSecondCard})
        else
            return
        end
    end)

    if gameOver then
        return true
    end
end)
```

Comment: Knowing nothing about Roblox specifically, I'd guess that what happens is that `OnServerEvent` might get called again each time you start a new game, and each time it will connect additional click handlers. To fix this, you would connect click handlers only once (e.g. outside of an event that can be repeated, or keep track of whether they are connected and don't do it if again if they are), or else disconnect the handlers when the game ends.

Comment: @tehtmi I didn't even think about that, I will try that thanks!